# Bluetooth BLE ILT254s

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I want to understand a little how a BLE module works. I have the following module ilt254s(the small version) but until now I was unable to communicate with it. Here is the [datasheet](https://fccid.io/document.php?id=2126527). I want to be able to communicate with it using a MCU over UART. I have the following questions:

1. Can I pair this with a laptop running windows 10? I have powered this up and I was expected to be discovered by the laptop but without success. Also, IOS and android phones and tablets were unable to discover it.
2. When powered up the RX pin P02 is 0V and TX P03 is 0V as well. So I suppose this BLE is not using the UART. Do I need to program the chip(CC2540) in order to set UART active on P0? If yes how can I program it?
3. How should I do in order to have it discovered and have it communicate with another MCU?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you already find out anything? I have the same module in front of me in a device I want to hack. Any idea how to connect it to your own app or read the raw data using a computer and ble stick?

Comment: Hello Thomas, Unfortunately I wasn't active too much in the last period. I did not find anything and I long ago switch to Cypress BLE and nordic nRF chips.